# ValueError: Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having trouble with building a Functional Keras model with a customized Keras layer. The goal is to get a model whose output is that of a regular function expressed in terms of a customized Keras layer. My code is based on the `ComputeSum` Layer class found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer).

Imports:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, Input
```

Customized Layer (non-trainable):

```
class ComputeSum(Layer):

  def __init__(self, input_dim):
      super(ComputeSum, self).__init__()
      # Create a non-trainable weight.
      self.total = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros((input_dim,)),
                               trainable=False)

  def call(self, inputs):
      self.total.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(inputs, axis=0))
      return self.total
```

Model:

```
def ComputeSumModel(tensor):
    inputs = Input(shape = tf.shape(tensor))
    outputs = ComputeSum(len(tensor))(tensor)
    
    model = keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs)

    return model
```

Testing directly on customized Layer:

```
these = tf.ones((4,4))

that = ComputeSum(len(these))

those = that(these)

those.numpy()
```

Result:
`array([4., 4., 4., 4.], dtype=float32)`

Testing using model function:

```
those = ComputeSumModel(these)
```

Result: `ValueError: Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow 'Layer' (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([4., 4., 4., 4.], dtype=float32)>`

What am I doing wrong here? It knows what the output of my customized layer should be, but it doesn't seem to like that output for the Functional model. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. I'm still new to Keras and TensorFlow in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to create your `model` object before passing data into it. Also your model's `input` has to be fed to the `ComputeSum` layer. Try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, Input

class ComputeSum(Layer):

  def __init__(self, input_dim):
      super(ComputeSum, self).__init__()
      # Create a non-trainable weight.
      self.total = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros((input_dim,)),
                               trainable=False)

  def call(self, inputs):
      self.total.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(inputs, axis=0))
      return self.total

def ComputeSumModel(input_shape):
    inputs = Input(shape = input_shape)
    outputs = ComputeSum(input_shape[0])(inputs)
    
    model = keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs)

    return model

these = tf.ones((4,4))
that = ComputeSum(len(these))
those = that(these)
print(those)
model = ComputeSumModel((tf.shape(these)[1],))
print(model(these))
```

```
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([4., 4., 4., 4.], dtype=float32)>
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([4., 4., 4., 4.], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I'm not sure I understand the reasons for why everything needs to be done the way you did it. I'll think on it and practice a few other things. If I have any other questions, I'd appreciate your input. Thanks again!

Comment: Take a look at how the Keras functional API works and you should understand everything.